# Find the value(s) of $n$ that satisfy the equation $P(n, 3) = 8n + P(n, 2)$

Tags: permutations

> Find the value(s) of $n$ that satisfy the equation $P(n, 3) = 8n + P(n, 2)$ where $P(n,k)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.

So far I have : 
$$P(n,3) = 8n + P(n, 2)
         =8n + n(n-1) 
         =7n + n^2 $$

How do I expand $P(n,3)$?

Comment: We have that:
$$P(n,3) = \frac{n!}{(n-3)!} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)!}{(n-3)!} = n(n-1)(n-2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have $$P(n,3)=\frac{n!}{(n-3)!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)!}{(n-3)!}=n(n-1)(n-2)$$
and $$P(n,2)=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)!}{(n-2)!}=n(n-1)$$
so we are trying to solve $$n^3-3n^2+2n=8n+n^2-n$$
or equivalently $$n^3-4n^2-5n=0$$